# How we can link my own design website to whmcs

Tags: cpanel, whm, whmcs

I am planning to start website hosting company as a reseller.I have big trouble about designing of my website for web hosting.I want my clients choose plans, register domain and create own cpanel account by registering on my own design sign up form.I searched almost every where but not find good tutorial about this topic.I have reseller account with cpanel/whm and WHMCS.I just want my clients choose packages and registered through my website instead of WHMCS design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your product in WHMCS with the cart URL and then assign that cart URL on your site so that when your client select plan, WHMCS will create account under your reseller account with that plan details.

You can add your product in your WHMCS URL with http://docs.whmcs.com/Products_and_Services URL help.